# Where does the oscillator frequency come from?

Tags: rf, oscillator

In case of a power amplifier I know the power comes from dc supply so it wouldn't be too strange to question where does the frequency in an oscillator comes from?
This question actually came to my mind when I was working on Dielectric Resonator Oscillator.Here the dielectric resonator coupled with the micro strip line is behaving as a resonator.So what is the transistor doing?[image]

I have also attached a picture of practical implementation of this oscillator i found after googling.I don't see a feedback in that one too.I just wanted to know the reason why writers call it series feedback.I am petrified that so many people down voted it[image]

Comment: Try showing a full circuit - the circuit you have shown contains now transistor biasing, feedback or anything that would make this into an oscillator. You don't even have a proper transistor symbol.

Comment: what do you mean,there are many type of oscillators some are quartz ie `Crystal Oscillator`which use peizoelectric property  and other are `Local Oscillators`,frequency means the time for one total cycle to occur,ie you can even get frequency using most simple oscillators and generators,like square wave generator,please give a brief diagram or atleast explain the constraints and terms.

Comment: The frequency comes from the resonator. The transistor provides gain. Not shown (apart from the bias as Andy says) is some means of feeding a little of the output energy back to the transistor's base (or emitter) to sustain the oscillation.

Comment: It is never shown how the output is fed back to the input and still it is called series feedback.I don't know how

Comment: Can you provide better references? If that schematic comes from a book, try posting some of the ancillary materials (related text, formulas, etc.) so we can understand the context. Some (entry-level) books about high frequency electronics are not focused on *electronic design*, so they skim over a lot of details in order to keep the things simple.

Comment: It comes from David M Pozar's book Microwave engineering.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: In many very high frequency oscillators the feedback components do not exist as tangible components.  The active device itself (a BJT) is unstable because of internal feedback.

The most important feedback elements are the capacitance of the junctions, rom collector to base, and base to emitter.  And the inductance of the leads to the device.

In this example they are exploited to create the feedback necessary to oscillate with the resonator defining the frequency of oscilation.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia has a fairly solid page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_resonator) about dielectric resonators.

It says:

> The resonant frequency is determined by the overall physical dimensions of the resonator and the dielectric constant of the material.

So that's where the frequency comes from.

In your circuit diagram above, the left-hand part is a transmission line passing close to the dielectric pill. It presents an impedance to the transistor, which has a narrow region of resistance (because of the dielectric pill) exactly as required for oscillation.

The transistor and output network form a simple amplifier, somewhat tuned to the frequency of interest. As Kevin points out, there will be sufficient feedback because of the transistor lead inductance and internal capacitance to maintain the oscillation. In fact, looking at the PCB itself, the thin 1/4 wave track leading towards the camera lifts the transistor ground at the target frequency. This isn't shown in the circuit diagram.

There is some DC bias required to power the transistor. You can see this in the example - a resistor to ground at the end of the resonator transmission line, and a thin 1/4 wave line, a (PCB) capacitor, and DC feed. There's also a DC blocking capacitor at the output.